# What is the difference between getattr() and calling the attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-collections

Here is a code I have written. I presumed both of them to return the same answer but they don't! How are they different?

```
from collections import deque
d = deque()
for _ in range(int(input())):
    method, *n = input().split()
    getattr(d, method)(*n)
print(*d)
```

and

```
from collections import deque
d = deque()
for _ in range(int(input())):
    method, *n = input().split()
    d.method(*n)
print(*d)
```

Comment: They are completely different. `d` is a `deque` object, and doesn't have a `.method` attribute. Note, this does not involve the variable, `method` at all.

Answer (score 2):

`getattr(...)` will get a named attribute from an object; `getattr(x, 'y')` is equivalent to `x.y`.

Where as `d.method(*n)` **will try to lookup the method named `method`** in `deque` object result in `AttributeError: 'collections.deque' object has no attribute 'method'`

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> d = deque()
>>> dir(d) # removed dunder methods for readability
[
   "append",
   "appendleft",
   "clear",
   "copy",
   "count",
   "extend",
   "extendleft",
   "index",
   "insert",
   "maxlen",
   "pop",
   "popleft",
   "remove",
   "reverse",
   "rotate",
]
>>> method = "insert"
>>> d.method
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'collections.deque' object has no attribute 'method'
>>> insert_method = getattr(d, method)
>>> insert_method
<built-in method insert of collections.deque object at 0x000001E5638AC0>
>>> help(insert_method)
Help on built-in function insert:

insert(...) method of collections.deque instance
    D.insert(index, object) -- insert object before index

>>> insert_method(0, 1)
>>> d
deque([1])
```